# Junit Interface Powermock

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

Edited:
Rewrote the question in a shorter way. Thanks for pointing this out! :)

I need to write JUnit tests where I have to mock a couple of private methods and fields with no setter/getter. I tried two ways to accomplish it, with Mockito and PowerMock. The question is, is it possible to combine those two?
First attempt to test a method with a private field:

```
...
@Mock private XMLConfiguration config;
@InjectMocks AAIGroupController groupi;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
...

    given(config.configurationsAt(anyString())).willReturn(ldapGroups);
...
```

Second attempt with PowerMock to test a private method:

```
...
AAIGroupController groupC = PowerMockito.spy(new AAIGroupController());
...
when(groupC, method(AAIGroupController.class, "getLdapGroupNodeFromGroupConfigFile", ELUser.class))
        .withArguments(any(ELUser.class))
        .thenReturn(sn);
assertTrue(iaigroupi.isPosixAccount(new ELUserAAI(null, true, false)));
...
```

Is there a way to combine them, or should I go only with PowerMock? I'm having trouble mocking the private field with PowerMock.

Another question is: I have to write JUnit tests for interfaces. Is this nonesense, as the classes implementing the interfaces are already tested. And if not, what would be good practice for it?

Thanks in advance!

### Old question, can be skipped completely. I just let it here for understanding the answers already given.

I have to write JUnit tests for Interfaces, where the implementation is already done. But I am getting a little confused how to properly write tests for them. I've started with the implementation, but I am stuck right now. First, I am not sure if I test the Interfaces correctly and then there is an issue with mocking a private field.
So far, I've wrote two different testclasses to try out things.
Both testclasses are "working" right now, but I would like to merge them into the InterfaceAAIGroupControllerTest Class, but don't know how to use Mockito within PowerMock.
For the Interface, I use

```
groupi = PowerMockito.spy(new AAIGroupController());
```

and for the other test I use

```
@Mock private XMLConfiguration config;
@InjectMocks AAIGroupController groupi;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

For the code:

Interface:

```
public interface IAAIGroupController {

/**
* Appends a new group entry
*/
public void appendGroup();

/**
 * checks if a given account is a possix account
 * 
 * @param elUser the user object to check
 * @return true if is posix, otherwise false
 * @throws ConfigurationException
 */
public boolean isPosixAccount(ELUser elUser)

...
```

The Implementation

```
@Override
public void appendGroup() {
    try {
        config.addProperty("ldapGroup(-1)",

        List<SubnodeConfiguration> ldapGroups = config.configurationsAt("ldapGroup");
        SubnodeConfiguration sn = ldapGroups.get(ldapGroups.size()-1);
        try {
            sn.addProperty("script(-1)", null);
            // TODO Configuration 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sn.addProperty("script(-1)", "default.sh");
        }

        config.save();
    } catch (ConfigurationException ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isPosixAccount(final ELUser elUser) throws ConfigurationException {
    SubnodeConfiguration ldapGroup = getLdapGroupNodeFromGroupConfigFile(elUser);
    String posix = ldapGroup.getString("[@posix]");
    if (posix == null || posix.isEmpty() || posix.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
        return true;
    } else if (posix.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        throw new ConfigurationException("posix attribute is not set properly!");
    }
}
```

Interface testing Code, not handling exception well for now, will fix that when it works..
I am using PowerMock as I have to call private methods in the implementation.
I don't know if I can test Interfaces well this way.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(AAIGroupController.class)
public class InterfaceAAIGroupControllerTest {

    public IAAIGroupController iaigroupi;
    public AAIGroupController groupi;
    public XMLConfiguration config;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        groupi = PowerMockito.spy(new AAIGroupController());
        config = Whitebox.getInternalState(groupi, "config");
        iaigroupi = groupi;
    }

    @Test
    public void isPosixAccount_True() {
        try {
        SubnodeConfiguration sn = mock(SubnodeConfiguration.class);
        when(iaigroupi, method(AAIGroupController.class, "getLdapGroupNodeFromGroupConfigFile", ELUser.class))
        .withArguments(any(ELUser.class))
        .thenReturn(sn);

            assertTrue(iaigroupi.isPosixAccount(new ELUserAAI(null, true, false)));
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Test code for the implementation, here I use Mockito to mock a private field which
is used in the code but is never set by a constructor or a method.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AAIGroupControllerTest {

    @Mock private XMLConfiguration config;
    @InjectMocks AAIGroupController groupi;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void appendGroupTest() {
        List<SubnodeConfiguration> ldapGroups = mock(List.class);
        SubnodeConfiguration sn = mock(SubnodeConfiguration.class);
        given(config.configurationsAt(anyString())).willReturn(ldapGroups);
        given(ldapGroups.size()).willReturn(11);
        given(ldapGroups.get(ldapGroups.size()-1)).willReturn(sn);
        groupi.appendGroup();
        verify(sn).addProperty("script(-1)", null);
    }

}
```

My problems right now are, can I test an Interface like I did? Doesn't seem to be a nice solution tbh. Parameterized seems unnecessary, as there will always be only one implementation and I have no clue how to use two Runners..
The other thing is, how can I use the testcode from the last example, where I mock the private field "config", within the PowerMock testclass? I don't know how to mock the private field correctly and change it's behavior when a method is called from it.

Thanks in advance for every tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three thoughts that come to mind when reading this:

- did you really need to post that much code and did you really expect us to read it all? Your question is very vague and hard to understand. Consider asking one question at a time.
- you don't test interfaces. An interface does not have any code, what is there to test?
- if you are using `PowerMock` for mocking, don't also use `Mockito` in the same test. Use one or the other as defined by your requirements

To set a private field, either provide a setter (possible at default scope) or use reflection (such as ReflectionTestUtils) to set it.

Comment: You just have to consider that posters here are not paid and mainly just doing it for fun. If we have to weed through a ton of code and if the question is not concise, most people will just move on to another question. You will get the most responses if your question is easy to read.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
It's my first time here, wasn't sure how much to post, so I thought better too much information than not enough, well.. :S
It's a requirement to test the interface, and I think the public API, expressed through it's interface, is an important point to test.
Nice to know, so I will split them by test.
Next time, if there is one, I will try to compress my question and only post the important points.
Thanks again for the usefull tips. :)

Comment: Whomever came up with that requirement need a lesson in software engineering or is confused between interface and abstract class. If you try to test an interface, all you are testing is the mocking framework. One valid option, is to design a test against an API / interface and then pass it one or more concrete implementations to be tested to validate that they implement to interface correctly. This design can allow for test reuse if there are multiple implementation of the same interface.

Comment: I will do JUnit testing only for the implementations then. Which kinda makes quite a lot of sense.. Tests against the API happens during the integration test, so this should be covered. Thanks for taking the time to answers a newbie. :)